# icc cannot compile a simple test program with macos because of incorrect configuration

Tags: c++, macos, icc

I have a very simple test program which does not actually do anything:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() { }
```

Compiling this with the following command gives me a very long error message:

```
icpc test.cpp
```

```
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm(640),
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__string(57),
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view(175),
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string(506),
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale(14),
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios(215),
                 from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream(37),
                 from main.cpp(1):
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits(1041): error: function call is not allowed in a constant expression
      __is_function(_Tp)
                        ^
```

It seems something is incorrectly configured, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Here is some version info:

```
$ icpc --version
icpc (ICC) 19.1.3.301 20200925
Copyright (C) 1985-2020 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 13.3.1
Build version 13E500a

$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: macOS 12.3.1 (21E258)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 21.4.0
      Processor Name: 12-Core Intel Xeon E5
      Processor Speed: 2,7 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 12
      ...
```

Comment: probably just an incompatibility between icc and libc++, you probably need to wait for an updated version

Answer (score 2):

Intel Classic compiler does MacOS* support for Mac* computers with Intel® Processors only. We can see that you are using the Unsupported version of the MACOS and Xcode versions.
please check the system requirements of Intel Classic Compiler from the below link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/system-requirements/oneapi-c-compiler-system-requirements.html

Try with any one of the supported OS versions(macOS* 10.15, 11.0,11.2 Big Sur, 12.0 Monterey) and Xcode versions(Xcode* 11.x , Xcode* 12.1, Xcode* 13.1).

Thanks & Regards,
Hemanth

Comment: I downgraded to XCode 13.1. The problem remains the same. I also added more lines from the `system_profiler` output.